# What number comes next in the sequence $7, 16, 8, 27, 9,...$?

Tags: pattern-recognition

What number comes next in this series?
$$7, 16, 8, 27, 9,...$$

I thought it was $38$, but I'm wrong.

It is a multiple choice, and options are $27, 10, 40, 37$.

Don't worry - I'm not cheating on anything, but helping my daughter with homework.
And I can't help her since I can't figure it out myself!

Comment: $42$ is as good as anything. There's no single answer, I'm afraid. The only sequences I know that you can say for certain what the next number is are [$640$, $231$, $100$, $91$, $\dots$](http://oeis.org/A027885) and [$5$, $10$, $20$, $30$, $36$, $\dots$](http://oeis.org/A027884).

Comment: $40$. I am sort of joking. There is  a semi-plausible pattern that does yield $40$, but the sample size is too small.

Comment: I'd have gone for $2^4 = 6$ or $4^2 = 16$ (both are equal), on the grounds that the terms are $7,8,9,\dots$ interwoven with $2^4, 3^3, 4^2, \dots$ or $4^2, 3^3, 2^4, \dots$

Comment: Oh I see how you got 38 I think. You looked at the digits of the even entries. And each digit increased each time over the even entries.

Comment: Like André, I came up with $40$: $16=2\cdot7+2$, $27=3\cdot8+3$, $40=4\cdot9+4$.

Comment: I guess I could have just said you did +11 each time for the even tries. This definitely seems like a possible answer 38.

Comment: I know this is my third comment, but does it really say what number comes next in the series? Or did it say sequence?

Comment: Actually, looking back it actually says 'pattern'

Comment: Hm, I see a prime, a square, a cube, a cube, a square, so if I'm expecting a prime next, what would be wrong with it? I guess there is a countable infinity of ways to look at this.

Comment: 3 votes to close and 4 up votes, we're surely a divided audience.

Comment: Too bad multiple choice did not include 38  a(n) = 1/4*((10*n - 3)*(-1)^n + 12*n + 23) for n>=1 
7, 16, 8, 27, 9, 38, 10, 49, 11, 60, 12, 71, 13, 82, 14, 93, 15, 104, 16, ...

Answer (score 8):

To me, it's $40$.

Indeed

$$16 = 2\cdot 8$$
$$27 = 3\cdot 9$$

thence

$$40 = 4\cdot 10$$

The even terms of the series may follow this path, so a possible series could be

$$7, 16, 8, 27, 9, 40, 10, 55, 11, 72, 12, \cdots$$

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is that the $1$st, $3$rd, $5$th, and so on, numbers are just increasing by one, so 
$$7,\_,8,\_,9,\_,10,\_,...$$

Now notice that $16=2 \cdot 8$, and $27=3 \cdot 9$. Therefore it would be reasonable to assume the next number to be $40=4 \cdot 10$.

Comment: This was also my train of thought.

Answer (score 5):

The next term is again $27$; then we had a palindromic sequence
$$
7,16,8,27,9,27,8,16,7,\ldots,
$$
repeating like this.

Answer (score 4):

$40$, because the sequence is $n+7$ and $n^2+10n+16$ interleaved.

$37$, because the sequence is $n+7$ and $-n^2/2+23n/2+16$ interleaved.

Use imagination and you come with equally good excuses for the other two options.

Answer (score 2):

Another view, also giving $40$ as the next term: $2n+2;\frac{n}{2};3n+3;\frac{n}{3};4n+4;\frac{n}{4}\cdots$
\begin{align}\text{initial value}&=7\\
7*2+2&=16\\
\frac{16}{2}&=8\\
8*3+3&=27\\
\frac{27}{3}&=9\\
9*4+4&=40\\
\frac{40}{4}&=10
\end{align}
Or: $2(n+1);\frac{n}{2};3(n+1);\frac{n}{3};4(n+1);\frac{n}{4}\cdots$
\begin{align}\text{initial value}&=7\\
2(7+1)&=16\\
\frac{16}{2}&=8\\
3(8+1)&=27\\
\frac{27}{3}&=9\\
4(9+1)&=40\\
\frac{40}{4}&=10
\end{align}